# How to create cards swiper Android

Tags: android

Hello I'm new programmer and I'm looking for a guide of how to create list of card that I can swipe to the side to remove a card like in google now.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[link](https://github.com/Androguide/cardsui-for-android)

Use this library. It is very easy to implement google now like card list using this library.